# Bypass " Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" dialog box

Tags: vbscript

I would like to know how to bypass **" Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" dialog box** using **VBscript** ..

I am trying to open a webpage through **IE** in **XP** and after I login this dialog box appears.. and the contents of the pages are loaded.

I would like to bypass the dialog box.. I tried with **Sleep** and **Send keys** but didn't work because when the page is loading the script waits for sleep time and executes but actually that dialog box doesn't appear during that time (ie its all based on internet speed)

I would like to have a nice solution for this which works perfectly.

Thanks to all..

Comment: better replace the tag perl with internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/how-to-turn-off-do-you-want-to-view-only-the/500bd75c-a104-407f-9230-3379de5c4133).

Here are the steps you need to take:

> A)    Open Internet Explorer and click on “Tools” and click “Internet
>   Options”.
>
> B)    Click on “Security” tab and click “Internet”.
>
> Under “Select a zone to view or change security settings”.
>
> C)    Click “Custom level” under “Security level for this zone”.
>
> D)   Scroll down to the "Miscellaneous" section.
>
> E)    Select “Enable”
>   under “Display mixed content”.
>
> F)    Click “OK” and “Apply” to save
>   the settings.